# unable to display table data in blade file in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Need display table data in laravel on show.blade.php file it is generated from TaskController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Task::all();
return view('tasks.index')->with('tasks', $tasks);

}
```

this is index.blade.php

```
@if(isset($tasks))

@foreach ($tasks as $task)

<h1>{{ $task->task_name }}</h1>

@endforeach

@endif
```

include this index with file to show.blade.php

```
@include('tasks.index')
```

but not generate any results???? No any error??? how to fix this

Comment: What is show.blade.php? I have a feeling that you are not using the right hierarchy

Comment: i include index.blade.php file to the show.blade.php file show.blade.php file display some other informations

Comment: yes but you are returning task.index as the render view, if you don't extend or include anything in it, it won't work.

Comment: then, what I should do to display data?

Comment: Post as much as you can from task.index

Comment: did you mean may I use form.blade.php for index.blade.php

Comment: You are telling your controller to render tasks.index, so this is your view, yet you are not showing what is inside tasks.index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that, is it an array or object. Try like below, it will work

```
@if (is_array($tasks) || is_object($tasks))
@foreach ($tasks as $task)

<h1>{{ $task->task_name }}</h1>

@endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: it is generated following error syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: can you add your index blade your question ?